# Qual o algoritmo para distribuir os parágrafos?

Tags: javascript, algoritmo, matemática

Eu estou lendo um trecho específico da Bíblia por semana baseado numa programação publicada no site [jw.org](http://www.jw.org).

Eu fiz um script em javascript que pega os parágrafos e versículos de cada capítulo e mostra a soma dos versículos.

Então eu tenho esta entrada: (Os trechos estão divididos em parágrafos, e o número em parênteses é o número de versículos)

```
1:1     (1)
1:2-6   (5)
1:7-10  (4)
1:11-12 (2)
1:13-17 (5)
2:1-10  (10)
2:11-16 (6)
2:17-18 (2)
3:1-7   (7)
3:8-9   (2)
3:10-13 (4)
3:14    (1)
3:15-17 (3)
4:1     (1)
4:2-5   (4)
4:6     (1)
4:7     (1)
4:8     (1)
4:9-10  (2)
4:11-18 (8)
4:19-22 (4)
5:1-3   (3)
5:4-10  (7)
5:11-14 (4)
```

Como eu vou ler em 7 dias eu preciso não apenas distribuir os 74 versículos para 7 dias, mas achar a melhor parada entre os parágrafos.

**Como decidir a melhor parada entre os parágrafos?** Deveríamos pegar a média de versículos por dia. Por exemplo 14,6. Então em cada dia nós iremos tentar chegar o mais perto do 14,6. Se em um dia o mais perto é 13, no próximo tentaremos chegar o mais perto do 15,6. E assim consecutivamente. **Porém**... fazendo isso no papel você irá perceber que às vezes é necessário decidir entre ler menos um dia e mais em outro pra mais pra frente ter uma média mais equilibrada.

Atualmente eu estou fazendo isso manualmente pois não consegui conceber um algoritmo para fazer isso.

Mas vou usar python para processar a entrada e estou pensando em fazer um algoritmo de força bruta que irá pegar todas as possibilidades de distribuição do número de parágrafos em 7 seções, por exemplo, **(3, 2, 3, 5, 5, 2, 3 )** que foi o que achei na mão.

Depois que eu tivesse estes números eu poderia passar uma função que visse qual era a melhor alternativa. Mas eu não sei que algoritmo usar para fazer isso. Talvez o algoritmo da **mediana**? A **média** não é pois sempre dará o mesmo número.

Achei este site: [Purple Math](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/meanmode.htm) que fala sobre "Mean, Median, Mode, and Range" (em inglês). Estou pensando em usar todos, menos a média, para achar o melhor valor.

Alguém tem alguma dica?

Comment: Nesse caso não faz muito sentido usar a mediana e a moda (ou esse tal de *range*, que não me recordo o que significa), sugiro se ater à média mesmo, que é o que me parece mais lógico. Se a média é 14,6, então você espera ter lido 14,6 no 1º dia, 29,2 no 2º dia, 43,8 no 3º dia e assim por diante. É desses valores que você precisa se aproximar.

Comment: Tem alguma coisa errada aí... Primeiro, a soma dos versículos deu 75, não 74 (como no seu resumo final). Segundo, **(3, 2, 3, 5, 5, 2, 3 )** tem mais grupos do que o apresentado (23, quando só existem 21 parágrafos).

Comment: Sim mgibsonbr, o meu script tem alguns bugs no momento que faltam corrigir. Obrigado pela observação

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apenas vá acumulando os valores e, quando for ultrapassar a meta (a média vezes o número de dias percorridos), verifique qual alternativa possui o menor [erro de predição](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual_sum_of_squares) (i.e. a diferença entre o valor encontrado e o valor esperado) e siga com ela:

```js
document.querySelector("#calcular").onclick = function() {

var entrada = document.querySelector("#entrada").value;
var dias = parseInt(document.querySelector("#dias").value, 10);

/* Interpreta a entrada */
var regex = /^.*\((\d+)\)\n/gm;
var match;

var acc = 0;
var versiculos = [];

while ( match = regex.exec(entrada) ) {
  var no = parseInt(match[1], 10);
  acc += no;
  versiculos.push({ texto:match[0], no:no });
}

/* Calcula o valor esperado (a média) e distribui */
var media = acc / dias;
var erro = 0; // Soma dos quadrados dos erros

acc = 0;
var valorEsperado = 0;
var classe = 0;
for ( var i = 0 ; i < versiculos.length ; ) {
  valorEsperado += media;
  
  // Verifica se acrescentar o próximo versículo terá erro maior que não acrescentar
  while ( i < versiculos.length && valorEsperado - acc > acc + versiculos[i].no - valorEsperado ) {
    versiculos[i].classe = classe ? "a" : "b";
    acc += versiculos[i].no;
    i++;
  }
  
  // Fecha a sequência do dia e calcula o QE
  erro += Math.pow(acc - valorEsperado, 2);
  classe = 1-classe;
}

/* Saída */
document.querySelector("#saida").innerHTML = 
  versiculos.map(function(v) {
      return '<pre class="' + v.classe + '">' + v.texto + "</pre>";
  }).join("") + 
  "<p>Média: " + media + "</p>" +
  "<p>SQE: " + erro + "</p>";
  
};
```

```css
.a { background-color: white; }
.b { background-color: lightgray; }

#saida, pre { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
```

```html
<textarea id="entrada">
1:1     (1)
1:2-6   (5)
1:7-10  (4)
1:11-12 (2)
2:1-10  (10)
2:11-16 (6)
3:1-7   (7)
3:8-9   (2)
3:10-13 (4)
3:14    (1)
4:1     (1)
4:2-5   (4)
4:6     (1)
4:7     (1)
4:8     (1)
4:9-10  (2)
4:11    (1)
4:11-18 (8)
5:1-3   (3)
5:4-10  (7)
5:11-14 (4)
-----------------
1:1-5:14
(74 versículos, 21 parágrafos)
</textarea>
<br>
Dias: <input id="dias" value="7">
<button id="calcular">Calcular</button>
<br/>
<div id="saida"></div>
```

O resultado foi **(3, 2, 2, 4, 6, 2, 2)**, com um SQE (soma dos quadrados dos erros) igual a `9.42`:

```
Grupos: (3,    2,    2,    4,    6,    2,    2)
Totais: (10,   12,   13,   8,    10,    11,   11)
Acc:    (10,   22,   35,   43,   53,    64,   75)
Pred:   (10.7, 21.4, 32.1, 42.8, 53.5, 64.2, 75)
QE:     (0.51, 0.32, 8.16, 0.02, 0.32, 0.08, 0)
SQE: 9.42
```

Comment: Obrigado mgibsonbr! Era exatamente o que eu queria! :D

Comment: @FilipeTeixeira Nesse caso, posso retaguear sua pergunta de `python` para `javascript`? Você disse que sua primeira parte estava em JavaScript, por isso fiz esse exemplo acima em JavaScript também (porque aí você já aproveitava a saída de um e colocava na entrada do outro), em vez de Python, que era o que você tinha pedido. (de todo modo era só um exemplo, para ilustrar o algoritmo, que de fato era o foco da pergunta)

Comment: Claro que pode.