# Algoritmo para distribuir verbetes de uma enciclopédia baseado em número de caracteres por dia

Tags: algoritmo

Eu gerei uma lista de verbetes de uma enciclopédia e quero achar a melhor maneira de separar os verbetes de forma que eu escolha um número de dias e eu tenha uma programação de quais verbetes ler por dia.

(A lista está aqui: https://pastebin.com/4qNLqCJj)

O primeiro item é o volume, o segundo o verbete, o terceiro o número de caracteres e o quarto é um id (gerado a partir da data que foi gravada a entrada no meu pc).

Eu gostaria de fazer um script que gerasse uma programação, eu entraria o número de dias e ela dividiria o número de caracteres total da enciclopédia e separaria os verbetes a partir do número de caracteres da média.

**Exemplo:** Eu entro com o número de dias, 120. O script irá gerar uma programação de modo que eu possa ler todos os caracteres dos três volumes da enciclopédia em 120 dias. Por exemplo:

A programação deverá ter 120 dias, sendo que cada dia terá um número X de verbetes tendo seu número de caracteres somado igualando um número mais próximo possível da média de caracteres por dia.

Os verbetes podem ser lidos em qualquer ordem e em qualquer volume, o que importa é eles serem distribuídos de modo que seja lido uma quantia quase igual de carcteres cada dia.

---

Eu fiz uma pergunta anterior relacionada a isso e um usuário sugeriu o algorítmo de erro de predição, mas não estou conseguindo adaptar ele para esse script.

Veja: [Qual o algoritmo para distribuir os parágrafos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/99977/qual-o-algoritmo-para-distribuir-os-par%C3%A1grafos)

Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Se eu entendi corretamente, o que você quer fazer envolve esses passos: 1) Calcular a média de caracteres por dia necessários para que toda a enciclopédia seja lida nos 120 dias; 2) Agrupar verbetes por dia, de forma que cada dia tenha verbetes que componham aproximadamente o mesmo número de caracteres da média. Se esse entendimento está correto, você provavelmente sabe fazer (1) mas está com dificuldade em fazer (2).

Comment: Uma solução "simples" é ordenar os verbetes do menor para o maior (isto é, menos caracteres para mais caracteres) e ir alocando-os nos dias até que ultrapassem a média calculada em (1). É claro que podem haver verbetes que sozinhos já ultrapassem a média ou que não podem ser combinados com nenhum outro sem ultrapassá-la, então nesse caso você tem que utilizar alguma outra heurística para fazer a melhor divisão. Algoritmos de melhor divisão são mais complexos e se relacionam com o famoso [Problema da Mochila](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_da_mochila). Talvez essa leitura te ajude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não li as outras respostas, e não sei maneira "inteligente" de resolver a sua questão. Dito isso, achei o problema interessante, e tentei resolver "ao meu modo" (na unha).

Imagino que você não queira/possa quebrar um verbete ao meio - se não você poderia fazer uma divisão "perfeita" e não teria aberto uma pergunta.

Digo isso porque percebi que você tem verbetes com 70 caracteres - e outros com 7000, o que dificulta (acredito) uma boa distribuição.

O que o código que eu escrevi pretende fazer, é o seguinte:

> Preencher a quantidade de dias desejada com os maiores verbetes encontrados
>
> Procurar pelos dias cuja soma de caracteres está mais distante da média
>
> Adicionar novos verbetes a esses dias

E é isso. Nos meus testes, o resultado parece razoável, mas confesso que apanhei tanto da programação em si que não pude testar muito as possíveis soluções!

> O programa espera um arquivo de texto, com formatação idêntica ao que você postou no [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/4qNLqCJj) - informação de cada verbete separada por **ponto e vírgula**, e verbetes separados um do outro por uma **nova linha**:

```
vol1;Ageu, Livro de;4629;1494553563.48
vol1;Agricultura;6593;1494553566.18
vol1;Água;8947;1494553571.57
vol1;Águia;10794;1494553577.0
vol1;Aguilhada;1688;1494553582.39
vol1;Agulha;580;1494553585.11
vol1;Agulha, Orifício da;1418;1494553587.82
```

---

> Resultado:
>   [image: screenshot do programa rodando]

```js
"use strict";
function mostraDados() {
 if (window.carregado) {
  document.getElementById("qtdcaracteres").value = window.qtdcaracteres;
  document.getElementById("qtdverbetes").value = window.qtdverbetes;
  if (document.getElementById("qtddias").value > window.qtdverbetes) {
   document.getElementById("qtddias").value = window.qtdverbetes;
  } 
  var qtddias = document.getElementById("qtddias").value;
  document.getElementById("qtdmedia").value = Math.round(window.qtdcaracteres/qtddias);
  window.qtdmedia = Math.round(window.qtdcaracteres/qtddias);
 }
}

function saida(div, texto) {
 div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + texto; 
}

function limpa(div) {
 div.innerHTML = ""; 
}
function criaVerbetes(meuArray) {
  var obj = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < meuArray.length; i++) {
   obj[i] = {
    vol: (meuArray[i].split(";"))[0],
    titulo: (meuArray[i].split(";"))[1],
    caracteres: (meuArray[i].split(";"))[2],
    id: (meuArray[i].split(";"))[3],
    pegaCaracteres: function() { return parseInt(this.caracteres); },
   }
  }
 return obj;
}

function contaCaracteres(meuArray) {
  var qtdCaracteres = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < meuArray.length; i++) {
   qtdCaracteres += meuArray[i].pegaCaracteres();
  }
 return qtdCaracteres;
}

function ordena(meuArray) {
  meuArray.sort(function(a, b) {
   return a.pegaCaracteres() - b.pegaCaracteres();
  });
}

function ordenaId(meuArray) {
  meuArray.sort(function(a, b) {
   return a.id - b.id;
  });
}

function listaVerbetes(meuArray) {
 for (var i = 0; i < meuArray.length; i++) {
  console.log(meuArray[i].titulo + ": " + meuArray[i].pegaCaracteres());
 }
}

function criaArrayDeDias() {
 var dias = document.getElementById("qtddias").value;
 var meuArray = new Array();
 
 for (var i = 0; i < dias; i++) {
  meuArray[i] = {
   verbete: [],
   pegaSoma: function() {
    var ct=0;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.verbete.length; i++) {
     ct += this.verbete[i].pegaCaracteres();
    }
    return ct;
   }
  }
 }

 return meuArray;
}

function calcula() {
 if (window.carregado) {
  window.objDia = criaArrayDeDias();
  window.colecaoVerbetes = criaVerbetes(arrayVerbetes);
    
                ordena(colecaoVerbetes);

  for (var i = 0; i < window.objDia.length; i++) {
   window.objDia[i].verbete[window.objDia[i].verbete.length] = window.colecaoVerbetes.pop();
  }
  
  var longeDaMedia = 0;
  var index;
  while(window.colecaoVerbetes.length > 0) {
   for (var i = 0; i < window.objDia.length; i++) {
   var provisorio = window.qtdmedia - window.objDia[i].pegaSoma();
    if (longeDaMedia < provisorio) {
     longeDaMedia = provisorio;
     index = i;
    }   
   }
   window.objDia[index].
    verbete[window.objDia[index].
     verbete.length] = window.colecaoVerbetes.pop();
   longeDaMedia = 0;
  }

  // saiu do while! hora de morfar
  var div = document.getElementById('saida');
  var div2 = document.getElementById('saida2');
  for (var i = 0; i < window.objDia.length; i++) {
    ordenaId(window.objDia[i].verbete);    
  }

  limpa(div);
  for (var z = 0; z < window.objDia.length; z++) {
   saida(div, "Dia " + z + ":<br>");
   saida(div, "soma de caracteres: " + window.objDia[z].pegaSoma() + "<br>");
   saida(div, "numero de verbetes: " + window.objDia[z].verbete.length + "<br><br>");
  }


  var div = document.getElementById('saida');
  limpa(div2);
    for (var z = 0; z < window.objDia.length; z++) {
   saida(div2, "Dia " + z + ":<br>");
   for (var g = 0; g < window.objDia[z].verbete.length; g++) {
    saida(div2, window.objDia[z].verbete[g].vol + ", " +
     window.objDia[z].verbete[g].titulo + "<br>");
   }
   saida(div2, "<br>");
  }

 } else { console.log("nao carregado"); }
}

function leArquivo(e) {
 var arquivo = e.target.files[0];
 var leitor = new FileReader();
 leitor.onload = function(e) {
  window.arquivoTexto = e.target.result;
  window.arrayVerbetes = arquivoTexto.split("\n");
  window.carregado = true;
  window.objDia = criaArrayDeDias();
  window.objVerbetes = criaVerbetes(arrayVerbetes);
  window.colecaoVerbetes = window.objVerbetes;
  window.qtdverbetes = window.objVerbetes.length;
  window.qtdcaracteres = contaCaracteres(objVerbetes);
  mostraDados();
 };
leitor.readAsText(arquivo);
}

document.getElementById('arquivo').addEventListener('change', leArquivo, false);
document.getElementById('qtddias').addEventListener('change', mostraDados, false);
```

```css
label {display:block;}
textarea {display:block;}

.container{
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color:#d6d6c2;
    display:flex;
}
.container2{
    color: #000;
    height:400px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
.divide{
    padding: 10px;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body> 
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
 <div class="divide">
   <label for="title">Quantidade de verbetes</label>
   <textarea id="qtdverbetes" rows="2" cols="15" readonly></textarea>
   <label for="title">Quantidade de caracteres</label>
   <textarea id="qtdcaracteres" rows="2" cols="15" readonly></textarea>
   <label for="title">Media caracteres/dia</label>
   <textarea id="qtdmedia" rows="2" cols="15" readonly></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="divide">
   <input type="file" id="arquivo"/><hr>
   <label for="title">Numero de dias</label>
   <textarea id="qtddias" rows="2" cols="15"></textarea>
   <hr>
   <button onclick="calcula()">Calcular</button>
  </div>
  </div>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="divide">
   <p>Contagem de caracteres:</p>
   <div class="container2" id="saida"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="divide">
   <p>Verbetes:</p>
   <div class="container2" id="saida2"></div>
  </div>
<script src=".\verbetes.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ola,

Bom os verbetes podem ser lidos aleatoriamente? exemplo no mesmo dia ler verbetes do volume 1, 2 e 3 aleatoriamente?

se não puder voce pode fazer algo como a logica abaixo:

```
Variaves do script:

somaDeCaracteres = soma dos caracteres de todas os verbetes
dias = numero de dias desejados
media = media de caracteres diarios
numeroDeVerbetes = quantidade de verbetes totais
caracteresRestantesNoDia = ?

Logica: 

1 - 
Para cada verbete em verbetes{
    somaDeCaracteres = somaDeCaracteres + verbete.caracteres
    numeroDeVerbetes = numeroDeVerbetes + 1
}

2 - 

media = somaDeCaracteres  dias

3 - 
caracteresRestantesNoDia = media
diaAtual = 1
Para cada verbete em verbetes{
    se caracteresRestantesNoDia - verbete.caracteres > 0 {
        adicionaVerbeteNaLista(diaAtual)
        caracteresRestantesNoDia = caracteresRestantesNoDia - verbete.caracteres
    }senao{
        diaAtual = diaAtual + 1
        caracteresRestantesNoDia = media
    }
}
```

Assim ele respeita a media, caso um verbete a mais em algum dia ultrapasse a media ele não adiciona... desta forma o ultimo dia tera caracteres a menos que os outros.

Comment: Os verbetes podem ser lidos em qualquer ordem e em qualquer volume, o que importa é eles serem distribuídos de modo que seja lido uma quantia quase igual de carcteres cada dia.

Comment: É valido começar a ler um verbete em um dia e terminar no outro? pois se for necessário terminar o verbete inteiro no dia que começou acredito que nao seja possivel dividir em quantias iguais....

Comment: Se eu lesse metade de um verbete hoje e acabasse amanhã isso significa que eu teria que contar o número de caracteres antes da leitura, o que não torna a tarefa muito prática.

Answer (score 0):

Resolver este problema não é difícil, o problema é a viabilidade devido ao custo computacional.

**Uma forma simples de resolver:** criar um algoritmo que gera todas as combinações possíveis e depois verificar qual varia menos em relação a média, que pode ser feito por exemplo, verificando qual tem o menor desvio quadrático, o que é algo fácil.

A dificuldade deste problema é devido a sua complexidade que cresce de forma exponencial, ou seja, seu custo computacional aumenta muito ao aumentar o tamanho do problema.

Sugiro que veja este vídeo que explica muito bem isso (apesar de ser em espanhol está bem compreensível). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UR2oDYZ-Sao

É obvio que na solução que eu dei, você pode simplificar algumas coisas para não ter que testar todas as combinações e encontrar uma solução melhor, porém a solução continuará sendo de complexidade exponencial.

Com 120 dias e 4321 verbetes, o tempo para encontrar a resposta será absurdamente grande, mas é a única forma de garantir que a melhor distribuição foi encontrada.

O que pode ser feito é desenvolver uma ideia para uma solução **não** ideal, onde você não irá encontrar a melhor distribuição, mas que talvez o resultado seja satisfatório para seu objetivo, porém isto depende do seu objetivo. Se era somente a melhor solução, infelizmente não há muito o que fazer, mas se uma solução não ideal também for válida podemos tentar algumas ideias. A pergunta que fica é qual seu objetivo?

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Não me importo muito com tempo computacional já que levei mais de 6 horas rodando 3 scripts que extraíram os verbetes da enciclopédia. Como dito na pergunta, meu objetivo é fazer uma programação que me permita ler igualmente um número de caracteres X a cada dia. Isso quer dizer que eu vou ler alguns verbetes hoje, alguns amanhã, mas no fim do número de dias eu terei lido os três volumes. Só que o detalhe é o número de combinações será astronômico já que eu poderia ler de 1 a vários verbetes por dia. Acredito que o script deve ser mais inteligente.

Comment: Realmente, "criar um algoritmo que gera todas as combinações possíveis" é uma solução de complexidade fatorial que vai muito rapidamente se tornar inviável conforme cresce o número de verbetes. Mais informações aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56836/defini%c3%a7%c3%a3o-da-nota%c3%a7%c3%a3o-big-o